# Execution in a node async series block does not wait for callback to fire

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a requirement to implement a REST API synchronously so that it returns a list of Objects. So the toplevel method is implemented as follows, where the method listObjs() should execute synchronously, and return the objects that are available, so they can be returned in the REST response.

```
 var objs= mds.listObjs();
 console.log("Leaving the GET /objs API!! ["+objs+"]");
 res.json({ message :'"Leaving the GET /objs API!! ['+objs+']'})
```

In the method listObjs() I am using async.series to break the processing into phases, to be executed one after the other. The first phase will obtain the Objects, and the second phase will process them and return a subset to the caller. The method getHttpRequest uses a callback internally to capture the result of the request. As can be seen, I am using this callback to execute the async callback. This should inform async.series to move to the next phase.

```
  listObjs : function() {
      async.series([
           function (callback) {
               console.log("Before getHttp");
               getHttpRequest(httpQuery,
                       function(responseStatusCode, objectsJson) {
                               console.log("Now Trigger the next async step")
                               callback(null, objectsJson); // trigger next step
                        });
               console.log("After getHttp");
            },
            function (callback) {
                console.log("Next Step, process the returned Objects");
                callback(null, "2");
            }
        ],
        function (err, result) {
             console.log("At end of async block "+result);
        });
        console.log("Leaving listObjs, SHOULD BE AFTER THE NEXT STEP IS CALLED");
    },
```

What I observe is that the async.series block does not wait until its callback is called. Instead the execution thread seems to jump out of the async bloc, and the top-level method returns before its result is available.:-

1. Before getHttp
2. After getHttp
3. Leaving listObjs, SHOULD BE AFTER THE NEXT STEP IS CALLED
4. Leaving the GET /objs API!! []
5. Now Trigger the next async step
6. Next Step, process the returned Objects, result=
7. At end of async block [{"name":"obj1"},{"name":"obj2"}],2

So why is the async.series block being exited before my second phase is executed?
That is, why is message 4. not at the end of my trace messages?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Your list is really hard to correlate to your code, could you comment each number of that list to the corresponding area in your snippet?

Answer (score 1):

The output is correct ! they are async and they will be executed when their own tasks is completed. Here is your complete code

```
var data = {};
var getData = function (callback) {

  // this is asyn task, it will take time to complete
  getHttpRequest(httpQuery, function(responseStatusCode, objectsJson) {

    // save your data
    data = objectsJson;
    callback(null, objectsJson); // trigger next step, objectsJson will be avaible at the last callback
  });

  // meanwhile this line will be executed
  console.log("I will be executed");
}


var processData = function (callback) {
  // do your job here, with data varibale

  // callback(err, result)
  // if you envoke callback with error then next function of the async.series will not be executed
  if(someThingGoWrong)
    return callback(new Error("Your error")); //  TagOne

}

var anotherTask = function(callback){
  if(someThingGoWrong)
    return callback("You can also send error as a string"); // TagTwo

  // another tasks
  data =  updatedValues
}

var finalHandler = function (err, result) {
  // if any error happen in TagOne or TagTwo
  // this final handler will be immediate executed

  // so handle error here

  if(err) return res.status(400).json(message:"Something bad happend");

  res.status(200).json({message: 'ok', data:data});
}

// execute the series
async.series([getData, processData, anotherTask], finalHandler);
```